# Java Mockito object is mocked but throws NullPointerException

Tags: java, mockito

I'm trying to mock my service class but I can't mock my service.
The service class:

```
@Service
class SomeService {
  private final Mapper mapper;
  private final Client sourceClient;
  private final Client destinationClient;

  public SomeService(Configuration configuration, Mapper mapper) {
   this.mapper = mapper;
   this.sourceClient = configuration.getSourceClient();
   this.destinationClient = configuration.getDestinationClient();
  }
  private Object fetch() {
   sourceClient.getData();
  }

 public List<MyClass> doLogic() {
  // do some logic here...
  Object dataFromClient = fetch()
 }
}

@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class SomeServiceTest {
 @InjectMocks
 private SomeService someService;
 @Mock
 private Client sourceClient;
 @Mock Client destinationClient;
 @Mock Configuration configuration;
 @Mock Mapper mapper;

 @Test
 void test() {
  // given
   when(sourceClient.getData().getItems()).thenReturn(preparedData());
  // when
  someService.doLogic();
 }

 private Object prepareData() {
  return new Object();
 }
```

I'm getting NullPointerException as it is now. I've noticed that the source of the problem is to call method getItems() in 'when(sourceClient.getData().getItems())'. When there is just getData() there is no NullPointerException but I would like to use getData().getItems(). Is there any way to mock or spy on that methods ? I would like to avoid mocking just getData() because of the object required to mock it.

Comment: you are not actually testing anything. please show a reproducible example

Comment: the code you posted won't even compile, let alone that it can reproduce the issue

Answer (score 1):

You are using a mock of `Configuration`,
but you are not stubbing either the
`configuration.getSourceClient()` method or
the `configuration.getDestinationClient()` method.

Because of this,
`sourceClient` is null in the `SomeService.fetch()` method.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I think that is not the case. I think I found the source of the problem that is calling other methods on the sourceClient like `when(sourceClient.getData().getItems())` and that is why it throws null pointer. If I go with just sourceClient.getData() there is no null pointer exception. I know in my question is just sourceClient.getData() but didn't realise this before. Do you know maybe how to mock or use spy to pretend the behaviour of this `sourceClient.getData().getItems()`

Comment: @DwB can you check my question as well

Comment: @sashabeliy add a link to your question as a comment here.

Comment: @Dwb Following my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71876957/parameter-specified-as-non-null-is-null-method-com-craftboxx-toolbar-headerda thanks beforehand

Comment: @sashabeliy sorry I can't help, I never picked up kotlin.

Answer (score 0):

@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class) indicates you are using junit5. so make sure you also use the @Test annotation from junit5 and not junit4